# Is it correct to say "to save on the electricity bill" instead of "to save money on the electricity bill"?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I heard both phrases, but the first seems to be wrong, but I am wondering if the omission of the word money is allowed in the English grammar, and why is it allowed? Is it allowed in British English and is it considered to be part of informal language?

Comment: It's the same exact meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Words are often omitted when they are clear from the context. I can say

> I ate at a restaurant yesterday.

I don't have to say "I ate *food* ...", it is implied by the context and the meaning of the word "ate".  Similarly "Save on your electricity bill" implies "save money" since a bill is a demand for money and so the context makes it clear.

This is not particularly informal. It is plain, normal language that could be used in a wide range of registers, from formal to informal.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/save

> intransitive verb
>   
> 1 : to rescue or deliver someone
>   
> 2a : to put aside money
>   
> b : to avoid unnecessary waste or expense : ECONOMIZE
>   
> c : to spend less money

So, yes, using meaning 2c, one can say "save on the electricity bill" to mean "spend less money on the electricity bill".